# Count occurrences of elements in a vector that occur in another vector

Tags: r, vector, count

I'm trying to count the occurrences of the elements in a vector that occur in another vector.

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
```

How many times do 1,2,3 occur in v2?
desired result `3,3,0`

This, `tabulate(match(v2, v1))`, returns

```
3,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `levels` set as 'v1' and then use `table` or `tabulate`

```
table(factor(v2, levels = v1))
# 1 2 3 
# 3 3 0
```

Or

```
tabulate(factor(v2, levels = v1), length(v1))
#[1] 3 3 0
```

Or in this case

```
tabulate(v2, length(v1))
#[1] 3 3 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option could be:

```
colSums(sapply(v1, `==`, v2))

[1] 3 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [the approach by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64506582/12158757) is the easiest. Here is another option but not that simple

```
> sapply(setNames(v1,v1),function(x) sum(v2 %in% x))
1 2 3
3 3 0
```